# Find names of all tables with more than x rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I can easily find all the tables of the form `_%_jobs` through the following query:

```
select * from pg_tables where tablename like '_%_jobs'
```

I would like to filter this list so that is is only the tables that have more than 200,000 rows.

---

I have tried:

```
select * from pg_tables where tablename like '_%_jobs' having count(*) > 200000
```

but this results in an error:

> ERROR:  column "pg_tables.schemaname" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: you are trying to check if the number of tables returned by the query are > 200000. You need to use dynamic sql to get the counts from each of the tables returned.

Comment: @vkp that makes sense. I have not used dynamic sql before so I am not entirely sure how to go about that

Comment: you can use vacuum analyze statistics for that

Comment: @Vao: Depends if OP doesn't mind using values that are not up-to-date.

Comment: @sstan yes - but counting it in dynamic sql can be painfull - imaging table of billion rows - and up to date number is valid for microseconds

Comment: @Vao: Totally agree. I'm just saying that when recommending to use statistics, it should always be mentioned with the extra little caution that the values will not be accurate, so that OP can make an informed decision. Otherwise, poeple may get the wrong impression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT relname, reltuples from pg_class where relname like '_%_jobs'
```

There maybe slight discrepancies between the numbers reported here and actual. From the manual section on [reltuples](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-class.html):

> Number of rows in the table. This is only an estimate used by the
>   planner. It is updated by VACUUM, ANALYZE, and a few DDL commands such
>   as CREATE INDEX.

Comment: For my purposes this is perfect, to specifically answer the question I did add `WHERE reltuples > 200000`

Comment: glad to have been of help